# Set selected value of a combo box

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've done a bit of searching on this, but nothing seems to have quite exactly the answer I'm looking for. Basically I have a combo box and an object in the combo box. I'd like to set the value of the combo box to the value of the object.

```
ComboBox cbPayee;
// populate with a bunch of "Payee" objects
Payee myObj; // this is my payee object which I get from my database

cbPayee.SelectedValue = myObj // this is what I'd like to do, but it doesn't work
```

I'm thinking that maybe this has something to do with the fact that the Payee object in the combo box is a different memory location than myObj, but I'm not sure how to overcome this.

**EDIT**

This is how the ComboBox is populated

```
foreach(Payee payee in PayeeManager.GetPayees())
{
    cbPayee.Items.Add(payee);
}
```

**EDIT #2**

I'm fairly new to WPF so maybe my binding is not set up properly?

```
<Window x:Class="Budget.TransactionWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="New Transaction" Height="450" Width="450" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PayeeOutput" DataType="Budget.LINQ.Payee">
            <StackPanel Margin="0 0 0 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="bold" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="73,50,0,0" Name="cbPayee" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PayeeOutput}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: How do you populate the combo box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested this and it works for me.  It's general concept code, but I hope it helps.

MyView.xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox Name="cbPayee" ItemsSource="{Binding Payees}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID"  />
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Click me" />
</StackPanel>
```

MyView.cs

```
public MyView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadItems();
    DataContext = this;
}

public IEnumerable<Payee> Payees { get; set; }

private void LoadItems()
{
    Payees = PayeeManager.GetPayees();
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cbPayee.SelectedValue = new Payee(2, "Steve").ID;
}
```

Payee.cs

```
public class Payee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Payee() { }
    public Payee(int id, string name)
    {
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Technically, I'd encourage you to use a MVVM approach where a View Model serves as the data context for the View, but this should get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you can do

```
cbPayee.SelectedItem = myObj;
```

When you do

```
cbPayee.SelectedValue = myObj;
```

what happens is that .NET searches for a `Payee` object with the property specified by the `ComboBox.SelectedValuePath` being equal to `myObj` (which will most certainly be no object at all), finds no such object, and as a result clears the selection.

**Update:**

Setting `SelectedItem` should simply "just work": if the object is in the `Items` collection, it gets selected. One caveat here is that when searching for the object, WPF will by default use *reference equality*. If you want to provide your own equality test for this scenario, you need to have `Payee` implement `IEquatable<Payee>`. If it doesn't work for you, double check that you are indeed referring to the same instance (or implement `IEquatable`).

Also, if you do:

```
cbPayee.SelectedValuePath = "Name";
cbPayee.SelectedValue = "Jack Smith";
```

then the combo box should select the `Payee` instance with its `Name` equal to what you specify. In practice, this is quite like implementing `IEquatable<Payee>` by having the implementation compare the value of `Name`.

What exactly is it that does not work for you?

Comment: Echoing Oded above: how do you add items to the combobox?

Answer (score -1):

in this case, I think you need to overrides the .ToString() with the "selectedvalue" inside the Payee object

Comment: If that was an answer to my post, I will say of course. The ToString() has to return the same value as the value shown in the combobox.

Answer (score -1):

You're using SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem, so your = operator is matching on the object's property that matches your ComboBox's ValueMember instead of the object's address.

If you're using an internal/static list of objects, you'll notice that SelectedValue is ALWAYS NULL.  If you're binding the ComboBox's DataSource, then you can set the SelectedValue = myObj.MyProperty, where MyProperty is the same as the ComboBox's ValueMember.

Example:

```
cbPayee.DisplayMember = "Name";
cbPayee.ValueMember = "ID";
cbPayee.DataSource = myPayeeCollection; // or SqlDataReader, or whatever

...

cbPayee.SelectedValue = myObj.ID;
```

If you're using an internal / static list of items (i.e. via `cbPayee.Items.Add( ... )`), then you'll have to use something like (without setting the ComboBox's DisplayMember / ValueMember properties:

```
cbPayee.Text = myObj.ToString();
```

Comment: Oh, you're using WPF. Then yes, you're going to want to do your databindings differently. Give me a moment while I write something up for you...

Answer (score -1):

you can take a two different approach:

### the first one:

you can define the ValueMember of the combo box to the property, it should look for, when it is given a value (usually it the id of the entity):

```
comboBox.ValueMember = "PayeeID";
```

now when you give the comboBox a value like 4, it will search the list for an object which has the value of 4;

**second approach:**

---

you override the Equal() method of the Payee, to tell how two entities are the same:

```
public override Equal(object obj)
{
if (obj is Payee)
   return ((obj as Payee).PayeeID == this.PayeeID;
else
   return false;
}
```

now you can do the following to select an object from the list:

```
comboBox.SelectedItem = wantedPayee;
```

the comboBox uses the Equal method to get the wanted entity to be selected from its internal list;

remember: when you don't override the equal, the default implementation (AFAIK) will compare the references to decide the equality.

finally i should say that this approaches work for me when i set the DataSource of the ComboBox manually, and I'm not sure if it works in your way (Items.Add())

comboBox.DataSouce = new List() { new Payee { /*some properties*/} };